Unable to see Google Pay button with stripe PyamentElement
I have implemented Stripe PaymentElement on a website.
All other payment methods (card, cashapp, klarna and afterpay) working in test mode.  However, whatever I do, I can't get the payment form to display a Google Pay button but it is only displaying the 1 link button.
What I have done so far

I've enabled Google Pay and Link in the stripe dashboard.
I'm testing on chrome browser.
I have added stripe test card in my chrome browser.

I am using ngrok for HTTPS
I also added my Visa card in google pay wallet


I have seen various stack overflow discussions related to these and verified all the answers more specifically answer 1 by toxa_xa and answer 2 by soma.
When I did console.log("Payment request supported:", result); it gives me
{
    "applePay": false,
    "googlePay": false,
    "link": true
}

Code
  useEffect(() => {
    if (stripe) {
      console.log("Stripe initialized:", stripe);
      console.log("Total amount:", total);
      const pr = stripe.paymentRequest({
        country: "US",
        currency: "usd",
        total: {
            label: "Order Total",  
            amount: total * 100, // Amount in cents
          },
        requestPayerName: true,
        requestPayerEmail: true,
        paymentMethodOrder: ["google_pay", "card"],
      });

      // Check if the Payment Request is available
      pr.canMakePayment().then((result) => {
        if (result) {
            console.log("Payment request supported:", result);
            setPaymentRequest(pr);
          } else {
            console.log("Payment request not supported on this device or browser.");
          }
      });

      // Listen for payment requests
      pr.on("paymentmethod", async (e) => {
        const { error } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
          payment_method: e.paymentMethod.id,
        });

        if (error) {
          e.complete("fail");
          setMessage(error.message);
        } else {
          e.complete("success");
          setMessage("Payment successful! Thank you for your purchase.");
        }
      });
    }
  }, [stripe, total]);

Backend
def create_payment_intent(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            stripe.api_key = api_key
  
            # Create the payment intent
            intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                 amount=1099,
                 currency="usd",
                 payment_method_types=["card", "cashapp", "afterpay_clearpay", "klarna"],

            )
            print("Client secret generated:", intent.client_secret)
            return JsonResponse({"client_secret": intent.client_secret})
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in creating PaymentIntent:", e)
            return JsonResponse({"error": str(e)}, status=400)

What could be the problem? If anyone face any issue related to that your participation for answering this question will be really appreciated. Thanks!

It sounds like you're following this guide: https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button
Link will be displayed if you're logged into Link. You mentioned PaymentElement but also paymentRequest. You wouldn't use paymentRequest with the PaymentElement.
I recommend starting here if you're using the PaymentElement: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/payment-element
The demo should display GooglePay if you're set up for GooglePay. You can start with the quickstart guide: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/quickstart

Are you able to share a test link with me so I could try to reproduce the issue?
